# HSQLDB with mssql keywords table name

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I am trying to switch all junit tests to hsqldb (real db is oracle). Problem appeared when i tried to map .hbm.xml file that contains:

```
<property name="begin" type="integer" column="BEGIN" /> <property name="end" type="integer" column="END" />
```

Now during mem db build i am getting this info:

```
ERROR - Unsuccessful: create table BLOCKTIME (ID bigint not null, BEGIN integer, END integer, TIMEZONE varchar(255), primary key (ID))
ERROR - Unexpected token: END in statement [create table BLOCKTIME (ID bigint not null, BEGIN integer, END]
```

The problem seems to be BEGIN and END table names that are restricted for mssql as keywords.

Any idea how to ommit this problem?

Thanks,
Marek.

Comment: Why do you mention "mssql" if you are only using Oracle and HSQLDB? But yes `BEGIN` is a reserved word in HSQLDB (actually in SQL I think) and I'm surprised you could create such a column in Oracle in the first place

Comment: BEGIN / END is acceptable in ORACLE but its not in mssql

Comment: But you are not using MS SQL (at least you only speak of HSQLDB and Oracle)

Comment: True, but while i start using HSQLDialect insteed of oracle dialect hibernate treat BEGIN and END as keywords (and those are mssql keyowords)

Comment: Those are HSQLDB keywords, that has nothing to do with MS SQL. I'm really surprised that HSQLDB accepts the (theortically) invalid Microsoft style of quoting keywords using `[]`

Comment: HSQLDB accepts BEGIN and rejects END in this context. As keywords they are used in different contexts but END is reserved because it is used in CASE .. WHEN .. END CASE. Quoting with [] is not accepted by HSQLDB.

Comment: correct @fredt that was my problem, while u r using oracle diaclect there is no problem coz END is nor keyword here, but if u change dialect to hsqldb for tests or any other reason problem apperas

Comment: Next HSQLDB version 2.2.9 will accept END as a column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the column name:

```
<property name="begin" type="integer" >
  <column name="[begin]" />
</property>
```

Or

```
<property name="begin" type="integer" >
  <column name='"begin"' />
</property>
```

Comment: Thanks bro, such an easy solution :)